# How to get rid off the SET?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't want to have variables in the query. How should I do it?

Below is my MYSQL query:

```
SET @totalcnt:=(
    select prof.failed_attempt_count 
    from profile prof, app_user usr 
    where upper(usr.username) = upper("admin") and 
          prof.id = usr.profile_id and 
          usr.enterprise_id = (select id 
                               from enterprise 
                               where upper(enterprise_code) = upper("e100") ));

update app_user 
set cur_failed_attempt_count = cur_failed_attempt_count + 1 
where (upper(username) = upper("admin") and 
      enterprise_id = (select id 
                       from enterprise 
                       where upper(enterprise_code) = upper("e100")) and
                             cur_failed_attempt_count < @totalcnt 
);
```

Basically I want to get rid of `@totalcnt` and first `SET` command.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

did you try to add directly @totalcnt expression into your main query?
EDIT: wrapped around LIMIT 1 since it was searched the number of affected rows by the SELECT, ergo the count of lines

```
  update app_user 
  set cur_failed_attempt_count = cur_failed_attempt_count + 1 
  where (upper(username) = upper("admin") 
      and enterprise_id = (select id 
                           from enterprise 
                           where upper (enterprise_code) = upper("e100")) 
      and cur_failed_attempt_count < (select prof.failed_attempt_count 
                                      from profile prof, app_user usr 
                                      where upper(usr.username) = upper("admin")
                                        and prof.id = usr.profile_id 
      and usr.enterprise_id = (select id 
                               from enterprise 
                               where upper(enterprise_code) = upper("e100") LIMIT 1))
  );
```

Comment: This will give an error "You can't specify target table 'app_user' for update in FROM clause".

Comment: oh yeah, because the result is a table, instead of the exact replace try SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (@totalCnt content)
I am assuming that @totalCnt is a count, since the returned value in a procedure from a query and assigned is the number of affected lines

Comment: another solution could be to add a limit 1 to the query: this would make your query a scalar value, usable inside a < comparison (since not a table anymore)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion guys. I used a SELECT query alias.

Comment: yw, it was the last solution LOL, can you kindly post it as an answer?